# Returning Enumerable from db context based on example

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I develop an ASP.NET Web API 2.2, and I want my data from my `dbcontext`.

So far I've done it like this:

```
return _context.Client;
```

I want the same data to be returned as an `IEnumerable` type like this:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
                     .Select(index => new Client
                                      {
                                          Name = "John",
                                          Surname = "Smiths"
                                      });
}
```

How can I do it, and have John and Smith, replaced by consecutive data from context?

Comment: What do you want with the `Range`?

Comment: Well, nothing really, I want just the whole set from Database, this range is just example from custom angular/api2.2 template from VS 2017. I need that, otherwise angular throws an error about parsing to JSON. (Issue I'm trying to solve for over a week now, more info on my profile)

Comment: Ok, so, you can just return the Clients from the `_context` ... to force IEnumerable you can do `.ToList()`

Comment: Question; why do you specifically want to return `IEnumerable<T>` ? That doesn't really make sense as an HTTP frame, so ... why not just make it `List<T>`, `T[]`, or something more obvious?

Comment: Well, I'm trying all I could, the data that api returns, I want later fetch do angular component. The problem is only hard coded data works, when I return context I get Error in angular app: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.l

Answer (score 1):

`_context.Client` is already `IEnumerable` and can be used as is. For example:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(int fromId, int toId)
{
    return _context.Client.Where(c => c.Id <= toId && c.Id >= fromId).Take(100);
}
```

This is only a sample you might want to do a different query.

Comment: My point is that as long as the type inherits from `IEnumerable<Client>` (which it must, for your code to compile) then the `AsEnumerable` call is pointless. It is not needed in this context. It is needed _very_ rarely - largely to indicate a shift from `IQueryable` to "LINQ to Objects" (i.e. shift the LINQ execution from database to in-memory).

Comment: Note that while an `IQueryable<T>` (which `context.Client` is) is an `IEnumerable<T>` and the code does compile, you should not leak IQueryables outside of your DAL (cast it `ToList()` before returning it). Leaking IQueryables violates your layer separation and is going to lead to bugs and unexpected behavior that the compiler won't catch.

Answer (score -1):

Okey, something's changed.

I edited the getclient method:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public  string GetClient()
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        Error = (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        },
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_context.Client, settings);
}
```

And now, when I run it in vs I get an array with proper data. On IIS I also get an array, only it is empty - but no error.

Should I configure something in my Api in order to properly connect to DB? I've got conn string in appsettings.json, Startup addDbContext, anything else?